# Speech-to-Text from audio file (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, mediarecorder

I am implementing a Voice-Recognition recording feature in my app which saves the recording as a.gp3 audio file using `MediaRecorder` library. I now want to apply Speech-to-Text conversion on the audio file, does anyone know a way to do it? (Not using `SpeechRecognizer`) because the voice input needs to arrive from an audio file

Thanks everyone in advance! :)

Comment: did you found any solution for doing that?